# How do you read this in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

Im new to a codebase where they use flow.

I dont understand this bit:

```
const {
  headers: { location },
}: Response = await httpClient.post(getChangeServicesUrl(userId), newChangeService);
```

Can you please explain whats happening?

is it, destructuring location, and then whats the colon doing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {
  headers: { location },
}: Response = await httpClient.post(...
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const response: Response = await httpClient.post(...
const location = response.headers.location;
```

So first part is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```
const {
  headers: { location },
}
```

And `: Response` is a [type annotation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/)